# Javascript Printing Doesn't work - not printing full page

Tags: javascript, html, printing

i am trying to print full page but it doesn't work tried different codes but no success

here is tried code.

```
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 
if (window.print) {
document.write('<form><input type=button name=print value="Print"     onClick="window.print()"></form>');
}
</script>

<style type="text/css" media="all">
body{font-size:1em;}
table{font-size:0.9em;}
.price{text-align:right;padding-right:5px;}
.center{text-align:center;}
table tr{height:20px;}
@media print {body, html{width: 100%;}}
#top, #bottom {display: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="width:100%;">
            <table width="94%" style="margin-left:2%;">

             <tr>
                    <td width="100%" colspan="3" class="center" style="height:35px;">    <span style="text-transform:uppercase;"><b>ORDER TYPE </b></span></td>
             </tr>
             <tr></table>


</body></html>
```

please help me with it.

thanks

Comment: see this link:http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_print

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to render your page through javascript? If yes the following tutorial may help.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp

Recommend reading the following API of the tutorial

---

### document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = new HTML

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
body{font-size:1em;}
table{font-size:0.9em;}
.price{text-align:right;padding-right:5px;}
.center{text-align:center;}
table tr{height:20px;}
@media print {body, html{width: 100%;}}
#top, #bottom {display: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="width:100%;">
<input type=button name=print value="Print"  onClick="window.print()">
            <table style="margin-left:2%;width:94%;">

             <tr>
                    <td width="100%" colspan="3" class="center" style="height:35px;">    <span style="text-transform:uppercase;"><b>ORDER TYPE </b></span></td>
             </tr>
             <tr></table>


</body></html>
```

**note:** always construct you html properly. width is a part of style tag it is not a tag itself.